# error on heroku ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant WelcomeController):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have used a few simple rails commands, like rails generate scaffold and rails generate controller command

```
rails g controller welcome index
```

which created a welcome controller and an index.html.erb file.  Then, in routes.rb i uncommented the line

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

Now, when I run the server

```
rails s
```

It runs fine and I get to see my home page on 127.0.0.1:3000.  However, I am having trouble seeing it in production mode when i run rails s -e production, and when I upload it to heroku.  I'm getting a postgres error on my computer probably because I dont have postgres installed, but on the heroku logs it says

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant WelcomeController)
```

I remember seeing "uninitialized constant" when writing plain old Ruby, usually when the name of a class is wrong, but I'm not sure which class I should be looking at.  Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Do you have a file in app/controllers/ called welcome_controller.rb that has class WelcomeController in it?

Comment: Yes,  i have a welcome_controller.rb with:

`class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

end`
 and it runs properly on rails s

Comment: update: problem solved.  my heroku was missing welcome_controller.rb, as i had to run `git commit -am "Added Welcome Screen"` and pushed and now it works!  Thank you for your help, nice and easy solution :)